# django rest framework - object permission does not trigger

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following setup:

permission.py

```
def get_permission_level(request, obj):
    try:
        level = PasswordListACL.objects.get(list=obj, user=request.user)
    except PasswordListACL.DoesNotExist:
        level = None
    return level


class IsPasswordListOwner(permissions.DjangoObjectPermissions):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return True

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        print(get_permission_level(request, obj))
        if get_permission_level(request, obj) == None:
            print('false')
            return False
        else:
            level = AccessLevel.objects.get(pk=get_permission_level(request, obj).level_id).name
            if level == 'Owner':
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

I can confirm through my `print('false')` that the permission is being acted on and it is returning the correct value (I'm expecting `False`) however the view is still returning the data instead of a 403.

views.py

```
class PasswordListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = PasswordList.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PasswordListSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsPasswordListOwner,)

    def list(self, request):
        self.permission_classes = [IsPasswordListOwner, ]
        queryset = self.get_queryset().filter(passwordlistacl__user=request.user)
        serializer = PasswordListSerializer(queryset, many=True, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        self.permission_classes = [IsPasswordListOwner, ]
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        if get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk):
            password = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
        else:
            pass
        serializer = PasswordListSerializer(password, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

edit - changing the return on `has_permission` confirms the permission there is overriding my `has_object_permission`?

Doing this gives me a 403 (correct):

```
def has_permission(self, request, view):
    return False
```

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#object-level-permissions) states:

> If you're writing your own views and want to enforce object level permissions, or if you override the get_object method on a generic view, then you'll need to explicitly call the .check_object_permissions(request, obj) method on the view at the point at which you've retrieved the object.

So since you're not calling `get_object()` you need to be calling `self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)` at some point.

Comment: correct the problem is all the comments I see explain the documentation but nowhere had an example.  Here's what I had to do for anyone in the future: `def retrieve(self, request, pk=None): obj = self.get_object() self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj) serializer = PasswordListSerializer(obj, context={'request': request}) return Response(serializer.data)`

Comment: thanks @whoisearth. Been looking quite long for a solution to this issue. Thanks for posting and explaining the code needed.